# matplotlibでレーダーチャートを描画

Tags: python, matplotlib

matplotlibでレーダーチャートを描画したいのですが、うまくいきません。

以下を実行すると、新たに２次元のプロット図が作成されてしまい、レーダーチャートに反映されません。

```
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=12)
ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5], ["1","2","3","4", "5"], color="grey", size=7)
plt.ylim(0,5)
```

スクリプト全文は以下です。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
%matplotlib notebook

list1=[['5.0','4.9','4.8', '3.9', '4.7', '4.9', '4.7'], ['3.5','3.1','3.0','2.0','2.7','3.1','3.0'], ['4.3','4.3','3.9','2.6','3.6','3.9','4.2']]
index1 = ["cluster0", "cluster1", "cluster2"]
columns1 =["class","labo","job","access","facility","friends","life"]
data = pd.DataFrame(data=list1, index=index1, columns=columns1)

categories=list(data) 
values_list = data.values.tolist()

cluster0_list = values_list[0]
cluster1_list = values_list[1]
cluster2_list = values_list[2]

cluster0_list += cluster0_list[:1]
cluster1_list += cluster1_list[:1]
cluster2_list += cluster2_list[:1]
cluster0_list

N = len(categories)
angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=12)
ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5], ["1","2","3","4", "5"], color="grey", size=7)
plt.ylim(0,5)

ax.plot(angles, cluster0_list, linewidth=1,c='m', linestyle='solid')
ax.plot(angles, cluster1_list, linewidth=1,c='m', linestyle='solid')
ax.plot(angles, cluster2_list, linewidth=1,c='m', linestyle='solid')
```

Comment: 確認ですが、`list1` が数値ではなく文字列のリスト(2次元リスト)になっているのは何か理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 文字列にしている理由は特にありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

残念ながら、私の環境では『新たに２次元のプロット図が作成されてしまう』現象は再現されませんでした。
が、とりあえず現状 `"文字列"` として扱われているデータを `"数値"`して扱うことで真っ当なグラフが表示されることは確認できました。

データを数値として扱うには、データフレーム作成部の

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=list1, index=index1, columns=columns1)
```

に `dtype`パラメータを追加して

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=list1, index=index1, columns=columns1, dtype='float')
```

と書くと良いかと思います。

今回動作がおかしいというグラフの整形部

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, color='grey', size=12)
ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5], ["1","2","3","4", "5"], color="grey", size=7)
plt.ylim(0,5)
```

の部分ですが、現状でも問題なく動作しました。ただ、`pyplot`のAPIと AxesのAPIが混ざった状態になっていて（個人的に）気持ちがわるいので、

```
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_xticks(angles[:-1])
ax.set_xticklabels(categories, color='grey', size=12)
ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
ax.set_yticks([1,2,3,4,5])
ax.set_yticklabels(["1","2","3","4","5"], color="grey", size=7)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
```

のようにどちらか（今回の場合は後者）に統一するほうが個人的には好みです。

あと、データフレームを作成してからわざわざリストに変換するなど全体的に冗長な気がします。
データの持ち方を少し変更するともう少しシンプルに書けるのではないでしょうか

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

list1=[['5.0','4.9','4.8', '3.9', '4.7', '4.9', '4.7'],
       ['3.5','3.1','3.0','2.0','2.7','3.1','3.0'],
       ['4.3','4.3','3.9','2.6','3.6','3.9','4.2']]
index1 = ["cluster0", "cluster1", "cluster2"]
columns1 =["class","labo","job","access","facility","friends","life"]
data = pd.DataFrame(data=list1, index=index1, columns=columns1, dtype='float').T

data = pd.concat([data, data.iloc[[0]]])
data['angles'] = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(data))
data

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
data.plot(x='angles', ax=ax,linewidth=1, cmap='Dark2', linestyle='solid')
ax.set_xticks(data.iloc[:-1, data.columns.get_loc('angles')])
ax.set_xticklabels(data.index[:-1], color='grey', size=12)
ax.set_rlabel_position(180)
ax.set_yticks([1,2,3,4,5])
ax.set_yticklabels(["1","2","3","4","5"], color='gray', size=7)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
ax.grid(True)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: もっと基本的な使い方の問題でしたか、確かに私が少しいじっただけで出た図はリストの数値とかけ離れていたのでどうかとは思っていたのですが。

Answer (score 0):

この2行を：

```
plt.yticks([1,2,3,4,5], ["1","2","3","4", "5"], color="grey", size=7)
plt.ylim(0,5)
```

こちらに変えたら：

```
plt.yticks([3,6,9,12,15], ["1","2","3","4", "5"], color="grey", size=7)
plt.ylim(0,15)
```

それらしき図になりましたけど。どうでしょうか？
Y軸スケールの範囲指定の問題でしょうか。
[image: Example_Figure1]

Comment: 「新たに２次元のプロット図が作成されてしまい」ですが、`ax =` 以降のスクリプトをバラバラのセルで実行していたことが原因でした。
セルをひとつにまとめたところ、正しく表示されました。
これは質問文を見ていただいてもわからないですね。ありがとうございました。

上記のようにY軸スケールを変更すると、私の場合逆におかしくなってしまいます。（プロットした部分が中心に寄って小さくなってしまう）
そもそもの課題は解決はしたのですが、すこし不思議に思っています。

Comment: 私の場合はJupyter-notebookではなく、素のPythonでやっていますので、その差でしょうか。